# Double integral over an annulus

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

**Question:** Let $D$ be part of the annulus $1\le x^2+y^2 \le 4$ lying in the first quarter of the $oxy$ plane where $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$ and below the line $y=x$

Evaluate the integral $$\iint_D\ \frac{y^2}{x^2}e^{x^2 + y^2}\ dxdy,$$

**My attempt:**

I believe I have a domain however I am unsure as to whether it is correct due to the size of the integral being very large.

The domain I think that represents D is $$D= \lbrace(r,\theta) \ 1 \le r\le 3, \ 0  \le\theta \le\frac{\pi}{4}\rbrace $$

Is this the correct domain?

Comment: It should be $1 \leq r \leq 2$ instead, but you got the idea.

Comment: Ahh! Silly mistake! Thanks!